# Looking for an easier shell script for renaming multiple files with multiple patterns

Tags: linux, sed, rename, mv

I have a bunch of files with this naming convention:

```
file01_2018-10-05_123456.pdf
file01_2018-10-06_443352.pdf
file02_2019-09-20_222222.pdf
file02_2019-01-27_246821.pdf
file03_2017-11-22_654321.pdf
file03_2017-04-14_987654.pdf
```

I have a script that finds the most recent of each file number (`file01`-`file03`) and renames it to `T3031`, `T3032`, `T3033`, cuts off everything after the first 6 chars and appends the file's last-modified date. They end up looking like this (which is exactly what I want):

```
T3031-2018Oct06.pdf
T3032-2019Sep20.pdf
T3033-2017Nov22.pdf
```

It's just that the script seems long and ugly to me (there are 17 loops for `file01`-`file17`). I'm hoping someone has a more elegant solution.

Here's part of what I have:

```
for F in $(ls -t | grep file01 | head -1)
do
    RUNDATE="$(date -r $F +%Y%b%d)"
    a="$(echo $F | head -c6)"
    b="$(echo "$a" | sed 's/file01/T3031/')"
    mv "$F" "${b}-${RUNDATE}.pdf" 2> /dev/null
done

for F in $(ls -t | grep file02 | head -1)
do
    RUNDATE="$(date -r $F +%Y%b%d)"
    a="$(echo $F | head -c6)"
    b="$(echo "$a" | sed 's/file02/T3032/')"
    mv "$F" "${b}-${RUNDATE}.pdf" 2> /dev/null
done

for F in $(ls -t | grep file03 | head -1)
do
    RUNDATE="$(date -r $F +%Y%b%d)"
    a="$(echo $F | head -c6)"
    b="$(echo "$a" | sed 's/file03/T3033/')"
    mv "$F" "${b}-${RUNDATE}.pdf" 2> /dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sort and rename):

```
ls -1 file* |
sort -t_ -k1,1 -k2,2r file1 |
sort -ut_ -k1,1 |
rename -n 'm/^[^_]*(\d\d)_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_\d+(\..*)/; 
           my $f = 3030+$1;
           my @m = ("XXX","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
           $_ = sprintf "T%d-$2%s$4$5", $f, $m[$3]'
```

List out the required `file`s.

Sort the list by file number and reversed date order.

Remove all but the first of each file number.

Use `rename` to format the file names.

N.B. Once the file formats agree with your requirements, remove the `-n` option for `rename` and the files will be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [don't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

A shell loop:

```sh
for file in file*.pdf
do
    mtime=$(date -r "$file" '+%Y%b%d')
    num=${file%%_*}             # remove the first "_" and all following
    num=${num#file}             # remove the "file" prefix
    num=$(( 3030 + 10#$num ))   # force base-10 interpretation of invalid octal "08" and "09"

    mv -v "$file" "T${num}-${mtime}.pdf"
done
```

Or using the `rename` command (remove the `-n` option if it looks right)

```sh
rename -MPOSIX=strftime -n '
    s{file(\d+).*}{
        sprintf "T%d-%s.pdf", 3030 + $1, strftime("%Y%b%d", localtime((stat)[9]))
    }e
' file*pdf
```